# css matrix regex first four arguments pattern

Tags: regex

I currently have an operation in a Flex app that fixes broken matrix' in a CSS file, we check each line and matching it against a pattern (this works fine) but I want to replace the matrix with a fixed one.

#### We get fed

```
-webkit-transform:matrix(1, -5.55112e-17,5.55112e-17, 1,43.996,241.213);
```

From [Wallaby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Wallaby) (Trust me I don't want to be using this either) and my regex to match the first four arguments to replace with `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1` is

```
/matrix\(\d+.?\d+e?-?,\s?/gi
```

I don't want to repeat that expression four times for the first four arguments, how can I do this the best way?

**[edit]**

I have come up with this which seems to do exactly what I wanted, if there are any better ways I'm still interested.

```
matrix\(([^,]*,){4}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this appears to do the best job (for a simple search/replace)

```
matrix\(([^,]*,){4}
```

Thanks for your answers though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about original values then why not use:

```
/matrix\([^)]*\)/gi
```

To match everything between `(` and `)`.

**EDIT:**

You can try:

```
s = 'matrix(1, -5.55112e-17,5.55112e-17, 1,43.996,241.213);';
s.match(/matrix\((?:[^,]+\s*,\s*){4}([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,)]+)/);
```

And then use matched group #1 and #2 which will be:

```
"43.996", "241.213"
```

Comment: I do care about the last two arguments otherwise I would have used a wildcard, thanks though.

Comment: So you want to match `43.996,241.213` ?

Comment: those are the only two arguments I need yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use a positive lookbehind assertion (if your regex flavor supports it, I don't know which one Flex uses):

```
(?<=matrix[(])[^,]+(?:,[^,]+){3}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Then simply replace by `1, 0, 0, 1`

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/N3uAI5f0Iz7QNyNY)

Demo by [RegExr](http://regexr.com?36hmt)